# FullCalendar not displaying event times - fed from CFC

Tags: json, fullcalendar, cfc

I've seen this asked (and answered) a number of times, but thus far none of the solutions is working for me.

I have a cfc that returns json data to an instance of FullCalendar.

The returned data looks like this:

[{"id":2,"title":"Test Event One","start":"February, 17 2011 09:30:00","end":"February, 17 2010 10:30:00","allday":false}]

The event is showing on the right day in all the calendar views - but is showing up in the all day section.

I'm invoking the calendar like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    events:'getEvents.cfc?method=getEvents&returnformat=json',
    header: {
        right: '',
        center: 'prev,next today',
        left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,'
        }
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you're returning the date in the format the fullCalendar object expects. Looking at the [Event Object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) documentation, you need to return the dates in the following formats:

> start: Date A JavaScript Date object
>   indicating the date/time an event
>   begins.
>
> When specifying Event Objects for
>   events or eventSources, you may
>   specify a string in IETF format (ex:
>   "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a
>   string in ISO8601 format (ex:
>   "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX
>   timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've amended the CFC and am now (I think) returning UNIX timestamp format dates:
[{"id":1,"title":"This event","start":1289896200,"description":"This is an event","end":1289899800,"allday":false}] - still not displaying properly in the calendar though - appreciate the help

Comment: Check the casing of all your json return values. You're returning `allday, while the docs say it should be `allDay.

Comment: Thanks Dan - I tried to post yesterday that the change in date format and changing from allday to allDay did the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did on the `jason-event.php` and it worked

```
<?php

$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

echo json_encode(array(
    //May
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Cardio-Kick Boxing and Adult Kung Fu ONLY',
        'start' => '2011-05-28 9:30:00',
        'end' => '2011-05-28 12:00:00',
        'allDay' => false,
        'url' => 'http://maxfit.us/'
    ),
));

?>
```